A nonzero cuspidal automorphic representation has a nonzero Fourier-coefficients?
$\DeclareMathOperator\GL{GL} \DeclareMathOperator\Sp{Sp} \DeclareMathOperator\Ind{Ind}\DeclareMathOperator\B{B}$Let $F$ be a number field and $G_n$ the symplectic group over a $2n$-dimensional symplectic space over $F$. Let $\mathbb{A}$ be the adele ring of $F$.
Cconsider an automorphic cuspidal representation $\pi$ of $G_n(\mathbb{A})$. Let $B$ be the Borel subgroup of $G_n$ and $N$ be its unipotent radical.
Consider an additive character $\psi$ of $\mathbb{A}$ and let $\{\psi_c\}_{c \in \mathbb{A}}$ be the family of generic characters of $N(\mathbb{A})$ associated to $\psi$.
Then I am wondering whether there is a generic character $\psi_c$ for some $c \in \mathbb{A}$ such that the Whittacker fourier coefficient of $\pi$ with respect to  $\psi_c$ is non-zero?

Unless you impose additional hypotheses on $\pi$, the answer is "no".  There are many automorphic representations which are not generic at some place.  For example, if $n \geq 2$, if $F = \mathbf{Q}$ is the rational numbers, and if $\pi$ is generated by a classical cuspidal holomorphic Siegel modular form, the answer is no.  The reason is that every generic linear functional on $\pi_\infty$ vanishes.

@Joseph, thanks for the comment. Then is it possible that all the fourier coefficients of $f$ are zero for every $f$ in $\pi$ though $\pi$ is non-zero?

Right, every Fourier coefficient that comes from taking a character of the unipotent radical $N$ of the Borel can vanish for every $f$ in $\pi$.  The "problem" is that $N$ is very large.  Let $N_1 = [N,N]$ be the commutator subgroup.  Then every character of $N$ is trivial on $N_1$.  So, in terms of of Fourier coefficients, you are asking for an $f$ in $\pi$ to have a nontrivial constant term along $N_1$.  But $N_1$ can be quite big, so you are asking for too much.  If you replace $N$ with the unipotent radical of the Siegel parabolic, you will find nonvanishing Fourier coefficients.

@Joseph, thanks again for the comment. If one replace $N$ with the unipotent radical of the Siegel parabolic, how do we know the nonvanishing of the Fourier-coefficients? In such case, the character of $N$ is $\psi(a_{n,n+1})$ for $a\in N$.  Right?

Let $U$ denote the unipotent radical of the Siegel parabolic.  I only claim that there is some character $\chi$ of $U$ for which the $\chi$ Fourier coefficient of your cusp form $\varphi$ is nonzero.  This follows immediately from the fact that $U$ is abelian.  Specifically, you can Fourier expand $\varphi$ along $U$.  If $\varphi$ is nonzero, then because $\varphi$ is a sum of its Fourier coefficients, at least one Fourier coefficient is nonzero.

@Joseph, Thank you very much! I got the point. If $N$ is too big, the fourier expansion of $f$ along $N$ does not exist but if $N$ is an appropriate size, $f$ have the fourier expansion along $N$.
